# Cookies disabled message with Vaadin running under Tomcat 8 and Apache with proxying

Tags: java, apache, tomcat, vaadin

I have a web application based on Vaadin and deployed it to my Tomcat 8 web app server. To access the application without port number etc. I installed an Apache web server and configured the VirtualHost to proxy it through. The problem now is, that I always get the following message, if I try to click on a Button etc. in the web application:

```
Cookies disabled
This application requires cookies to function.
Please enable cookies in your browser and click here or press ESC to try again.
```

All cookies are enabled and I'm using Chrome browser. Also the cookies from this webpage are retrieved and are valid.

If I access the web application the normal way with the port specification, I can click all content without errors.

Comment: I solved my problem with the following answer:

http://serverfault.com/questions/397617/apache-mod-proxy-page-reload-and-sessions

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept that answer, so the question is closed.